# Using soundfonts with MIKMIDI

Tags: ios, audio, midi, mikmidi

Right now, I successfully created a MIKMIDISequence sequence. However, I couldn't find out how to tie a sound font to that sequence. My question is, how can I assign a MIKMIDISequence a soundfont?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting a soundfont on the sequence, you should use the [`-loadSoundfontFromFileAtURL:error:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MIKMIDI/1.5.0/Classes/MIKMIDISynthesizer.html#//api/name/loadSoundfontFromFileAtURL:error:) of `MIKMIDISynthesizer` to do so.

Assuming you're using `MIKMIDISequencer` to play back your sequence, you can get the synthesizer for each track using [`-builtinSynthesizerForTrack:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MIKMIDI/1.5.0/Classes/MIKMIDISequencer.html#//api/name/builtinSynthesizerForTrack:) on `MIKMIDISequencer`. Note that there is a synthesizer for each track in the sequence, so if your sequence has multiple tracks you'll can/should load a soundfont for each one.

Something like:

```
for (MIKMIDITrack *track in sequence.tracks) {
    MIKMIDISynthesizer *synth = [sequencer builtInSynthesizerForTrack:track]
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![synth loadSoundfontFromFileAtURL:soundfontURL error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading soundfont (%@) into synthesizer for track (%@): %@", sondfontURL, track, synthesizer);
    }
}
```